# Excel VBA attaching print area as PDF

Tags: excel, vba, email, email-attachments, cdo.message

I'm trying to create a macro whereby the print area of a sheet, "Hotel Booking" is attached as a PDF file to an email. The email will be created using CDO and not Outlook Application. Everything else in my code works except for the attachment. It will say file not found and will not attach anything to the email.

Here's my code:

```
Sub CDO_Mail_Small_Text2()    Dim iMsg As Object
Dim iConf As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim Flds As Variant
Dim PDFfile As String, Title As String
Dim printRange As Range
Dim i As Long

CarryOn = MsgBox("Proceed to compose Email?", vbYesNo, "Continue?")


If CarryOn = vbYes Then


Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")


    iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
    Set Flds = iConf.Fields


Title = Sheets("Hotel Booking").Range("AF17")
PDFfile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  i = InStrRev(PDFfile, ".")
  If i > 1 Then PDFfile = Left(PDFfile, i - 1)
  PDFfile = PDFfile & "_" & Sheets("Hotel Booking").Name & ".pdf"

Set printRange = Range(Sheets("Hotel Booking").PageSetup.PrintArea)



With Sheets("Hotel Booking")
    printRange.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDFfile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
  End With
    With Flds
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp-mail.outlook.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "xxxx@outlook.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "xxxx"
        .Update
    End With


With iMsg
    Set .Configuration = iConf
    .To = "xxxxx@gmail.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .From = " <xxxx@outlook.com>"
    .Subject = " "
    .TextBody = " "
    .AddAttachment PdfFile
    .Send
End With

'Kill PdfFile


    Set iMsg = Nothing
    Set iConf = Nothing
    Set Flds = Nothing

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
     MsgBox "There was an error"
     Exit Sub

    Else
 MsgBox "Email has been sent!"

    End If  'for error

End If   'compose email


End Sub
```

Comment: `Activeworkbook.Fullname` will return something like `C:\Users\quantamz\myExcelFile.xlsm`. Is your PDF name truly something like `C:\Users\quantamz\myExcelFile.xlsm_Hotel Booking.pdf`?

Comment: @BruceWayne only it wouldn't have the `.xlsm` since that gets stripped off with `If i > 1 Then PDFfile = Left(PDFfile, i - 1)`

Comment: Note that with `Set printRange = ...`, there's an implicit reference to the `ActiveSheet`, which without seeing your workbook may or may not be the "Hotel Booking" sheet. [`PageSetup.PrintArea`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-printarea-property-excel) returns just the `String` in A1-style reference.

Comment: i'm not quite sure how the code for the attachment works, I found it online. I'm a complete beginner with VBA and just want to be able to attach the print area of a sheet, "Hotel Booking", as a PDF file into a CDO email. The PDF file is not supposed to be saved on the computer after the macro is complete, hence the "Kill PdfFile". Something like in this code: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1010162-vba-excel-worksheet-selected-range-pdf-email-via-outlook.html